# If statement does not respond well with SQLite3 syntax

Tags: php, sqlite

I have this code that tries to retrieve some values from SQLite3 DB:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
   $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
} else {
   echo 'No keywords!';
}

class DB extends SQLite3 {
   function __construct($file) {
     $this->open($file);
   }
}

$db = new DB('mpsn.sqlite3');
if (!$db) {
echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
  echo "Successfully opened DB.<br/>";
}
/* DISPLAYING RESULTS */
$sql = <<<EOF
  SELECT * from glossary WHERE title LIKE '$keyword';
EOF;
$ret = $db->query($sql);
if ($ret) {//LINE A
while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Judul = " . $row['title'] . "<br>";
    echo "Link = " . $row['link'] . "<br>";
    echo "Deskripsi = " . $row['description'] . "<br>";        
}
echo "Operation done successfully\n";
$db->close();
} 
else {//LINE B
echo 'Not found';//LINE C
}//LINE D
?>
```

Without those Lines A, B, C, and D. The script works really fine. But I don't get it when I do the `if` function (in case the `$keyword` isn't found in the `title`), it didn't respond at all.

Even though I gave a keyword that is not supposed to be be found in there, it still gives the alert `Operation done successfully` (without doing the `echo` in the `while`).

So I'm guessing the problem lies in the `if` thing.
I change it into this on line D:

```
$ret->query$db($sql);
```

Still doesn't work.
What have I missed on this? Thanks.

Comment: The operation __was__ done successfully: no rows returned is a valid result - See JonScully's comment/note at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php

Comment: So how do I do that if I wanna say "no rows returned"?

Comment: Did you read Jon Scully's comments on the docs page? He provides a code snippet that shows exactly how to determine whether rows were returned or not

Answer (score 0):

I have done this learning from Mark Baker's comment, thanks.

```
$ret = $db->query($sql);
if ($ret->numColumns()&&$ret->columnType(0)!=SQLITE3_NULL) {
while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Judul = " . $row['title'] . "<br>";
    echo "Link = " . $row['link'] . "<br>";
    echo "Deskripsi = " . $row['description'] . "<br>";        
}
echo "Operation done successfully\n";
$db->close();
} else {
echo 'Not found';
}
```

I did not check if it actually gave the rows returned.